# mod rewrite to redirect all except the root

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

so I have SomeFunnyWebsite.com and ActualSite.com if someone lands on SomeFunnyWebsite.com I want them to see the funny picture but if they goto SomeFunnyWebsite.com/AnyThing I need it to redirect with a 301 to ActualSite.com

```
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://actualsite.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

But this doesn't redirect to anything. But I have verified that other redirect rules can work.

Comment: Define "do anything". Does `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://actualsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]` do "anything"? If not you need to configure your server to read these instructions properly.

Comment: Yes that redirects all traffic. When I say does nothing I mean never redirects them but displays the site as one would normally except, with a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a rewrite condition that inverts a match on `/` for the specific domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?somefunnywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://actualsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

I haven't tested it but that should get you started. (I'd suggest using a 302 to start as browsers tend to cache 301 redirects.)

Comment: Still just giving a 404 on somefunnywebsite.com/whatever

Comment: changing the ReqriteRule to RewriteRule ^(.*) http://actualsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,QSA]  seems to have worked. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer. Using a grouping doesnt matter, as `%{REQUEST_URI}` wouldn't be affected by it. Use a grouping like that if you redirect to `http://actualsite.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]` to make it work.